# Increasing Interval of a Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

In what interval is the function $f(x) = x^2-4$ increasing? How did you get the interval of the function, and when it is increasing?

Comment: Do you know differentiation, and the relation between the sign of the derivative and the variations of a differentiable function?

Comment: Uhm, I was expecting a [0, infinity) answer, I want to know the answer algebraicly first. Hahahaha, please don't include calculus.

Comment: Hint: Consider $f(x + h) - f(x)$ for $ x, h  \ge 0$

Comment: BTW, $f(x)$ _isn't_ increasing at $x=0$ : it's stationary, which means it's neither increasing nor decreasing.

Comment: @PM2Ring  Being increasing is a property of the function on a set/interval, not at a single point. I guess what you mean is "is not increasing on a *neighborhood* of $0$"?

Comment: @ClementC. That's a fair point.

Comment: This post is worded exactly like a homework problem. The goal of this site is not to simply do homework for others. We encourage questions that show what you have already tried, and where you got stuck. You can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: @user259513 Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 3):

Without calculus (as asked in the comments), you could have the slightly awkward following argument:

1. $x\mapsto x^2$ is (strictly) increasing on $[0,\infty)$ (can you show/prove that, or take it for granted?);
2. $x\mapsto ax+b$ is (strictly) increasing on $(-\infty,\infty)$ if $a > 0$;
3. The composition of two increasing functions is increasing.

Therefore, $f$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$. By parity, it is also decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=2x$, $f(x)>0$ on the interval $[0, \infty)$. Therefore $f(x)$ is increasing on that interval.

Comment: The inequality is only strict on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @ClementC. Correct, I'll edit it.

Comment: The OP wants a non-calculus answer. OTOH, I guess _anything_ that deals with the rate of change of a function is technically part of differential calculus... :)

Comment: Clearly, the function is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$. And I don't really think that derivatives are the right tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=2x$ and $''(x)=2$. If a function is increasing, $f'(x)>0$. That means $2x>0$. So $x\in[0,\infty)$

If $x<0$, then derivative is negative and function decreases.

Derivative is zero at $x=0$. So there is either a maxima or minima at that point.
since $f''(x)>0$ for all $x$, the $(0,f(0))$ will be minima of the function.

This is the procedure.

Comment: A derivative equal to $0$ at a point does not imply a local extremum. Look at $x\mapsto x^3$ at $0$.

Comment: For x^3, f''(x) is zero at x=0. So instead of decreasing and then increasing (forming a minima), the curve changes it nature forming a point of inflection. I have said that f''(x)=2. So no point of inflection.

Comment: I would say "may not imply extremum" instead of "does not imply extremum". But thanks for replying. I am also learning. So any feedback will improve my concepts.

Comment: If you have an implication that only holds some of the time (even *most* of the time), then it is **not** an implication...